# How to stop android emulator after executing the unit tests using pom.xml in maven?

Tags: android, maven, android-emulator, pom.xml

Can you specify a method to stop android emulator after running the unit tests using pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) and the integration test-related phases of the Maven lifecycle.  When you configure your POM:

- Bind the Maven goals to start the Android emulator to the `pre-integration-test` phase.
- Run tests with the Failsafe plugin `integration-test` goal, bound to the `integration-test` phase.
- Bind goals to shut down the emulator to the `post-integration-test` phase.
- Verify test output with the Failsafe plugin `verify` goal, bound to the `verify` phase.

Comment: Can you specify it in detail.the issue I was getting is that the emulator is taking some time to start before which the testcases are failing.

Comment: I know nothing about the Android emulator, so I cannot help with POM config there.  This is the pattern I've used in the past with plain Java development when running integration tests. For example, you might want to start an app container (Jetty or Tomcat), run integration tests, shut down the container, and then verify results.  The failsafe plugin docs I linked above should get you started.